# VB6 - set focus on a textfield on another form

Tags: vb6, forms, focus

I want to set focus on a textfield on one form, from another form. 
How do I accomplish this in VB6?

Comment: ahhh! It's the most evil tag in all the land: [vb6]!! =P

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have `Form1` and `Form2` with a `TextBox` on `Form2`,

In the `Command1_Click` of `Form1`'s Module:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Load Form2
    Form2.Show
    Form2.SetFocus
    If Form2.Text1.Visible And Form2.Text1.Enabled Then
        Form2.Text1.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set focus to a text field on another form if that form is not visible.
So you should check first if the form is visible

```
If (form2.Visible)
begin
 txtBox2.SetFocus()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that FormA wants to set the focus on Text1 on FormB I think you could just do something like:

In FormB create a sub called `FocusOnText1` and in that sub have the code `Text1.SetFocus` and then just call that sub from FormA.

As Jangwenyi says though, you need to make sure it's visible, so I'd suggest adding something like his if statement in the `FocusOnText1` sub since otherwise you might get errors (Error 5 I think).